# JAX-WS generate a WS client with protected or private constructor

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I am using JAX-WS to generate my jar client for some webservices.

Anyone knows if is possible to generate the webservices client using jax-ws with protected or private constructor?

I am using maven with cxf-codegen-plugin to generate the classes =)

Comment: Curious: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The class that will serve as a client of your Web Service could have a private/protected constructor, since it could call the Web Methods in its, well, own methods. What's your specific question/scenario? What have you tried?

Comment: I create a factory to serve all webservices because I need to inject in all of then the user credentials. So, If the programmer create a ws instance using the default constructor, he will receive a exception because there is no credentials in the request header.

I want to provide a unique way to use my webservices ... only by my factory.

Comment: a valid additional comment: I use maven to generate my web services client. Automatically ... This plugin use the default java method to generate called wsimport. I need to find a argument to pass to the command line to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be...don't compile it :). Have wsimport generate source files without compiling by using some combination of the `-s <dir> -keep -Xnocompile` options. You can then remove the generated service class before compiling. If you need to make use of the embedded information within the service class, you can use annotation processing to pull out the service name, namespace and WSDL location from the `WebServiceClient` annotation. You'll also need to replace any usage of the service class's constructors with one of the `Service.create()` methods.

Edit: My bad - I totally missed that you're using CXF tools (wsdl2java?). I haven't used them before, but I'd be surprised if they didn't offer similar functionality, so the general approach should still work...

Comment: Well. I think I need to use the "man -really wsimport" instead of the "man wsimport" command to see documentation on the rest of the flags.... Seeing -Xnocompile here is very useful. I wonder how many other secret options there are. I guess I may need to check out the source from Apache in order to find out.